# Query for a string containing a particular character

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Which SQL query will collect all the persons whose name include character“k”? The table name is “person_info” and the column for person name is ”name”.

Comment: The title is misleading. It led me to believe that question was about unicode!

Comment: I highly recommend you take this course http://w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: This also smells of homework without even *basic* research

Comment: k is very special indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM person_info WHERE name LIKE '%k%'
```

Comment: @UmaisGillani You should accept (or at least upvote) the answer then. tia! ;) And you should take a look at some basic SQL.

Comment: Ok dear, i m new on Stack overflow, and for the time being i have not enough reputation points for upvoting.